# Как дать права на запись в папке для php

Tags: php, linux, nginx

На сервере стоит *nginx* + *php fpm*.
Есть *shell*-доступ и *root*-овые права.

Папка с сайтом: `/usr/share/nginx/html/`.

Нужно дать правильные права для записи в папку `/usr/share/nginx/html/cache`.

Эту папку я залил через *ftp*.

Я так понимаю, мне нужно каким-то образом узнать, какому пользователю нужно дать права на эту папку, ну и собственно дать их этому пользователю.

Как это сделать?

Comment: у вас доступ к *docroot*-у только по *ftp*?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin заливал через sftp под рутом

Comment: это я понял. у вас доступ к *shell*-у на сервере есть?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, есть, это vps, самый простой вариант это на папку дать 777 но это не правильно как бы

Comment: я обновил ответ с информацией на случай, если в этом каталоге есть другие вложенные каталоги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

узнать, от чьего имени работают «дочерние» процессы *nginx*-а («родительский» выполняется от имени *root*-а — обычно только ему можно запускать процессы, слушающие порты с номером ниже 1024) можно, например, так:

```
$ ps f -C nginx -o user,fname
USER     COMMAND
root     nginx
www-data  \_ nginx
www-data  \_ nginx
www-data  \_ nginx
www-data  \_ nginx
```

в данном примере этот пользователь — *www-data*.

значит, его и надо сделать владельцем каталога, куда процесс *nginx*-а должен иметь право записи:

```
$ sudo chown www-data /путь/к/каталогу
```

для пущей надёжности можно добавить биты *rwx* для владельца каталога (хотя вряд ли они отсутствуют):

```
$ sudo chmod u+rwx /путь/к/каталогу
```

---

если внутри этого каталога есть другие каталоги, в которые *nginx* тоже должен иметь возможность записывать, то вместо этих команд можно использовать, например, такие:

```
$ sudo find /путь/к/каталогу -type d -exec chown www-data {} +
$ sudo find /путь/к/каталогу -type d -exec chmod u+rwx {} +
```