# Nginx не загружает файл в директорию с 755 правами

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Серевер работал на apache + nginx. Все работало нормально. На php через форму загружался аватар и любые другие изображения.
Перешел на связку nginx + phpfpm. Стал кидать 500 Server Error при загрузке любого файла на сервер через post. Начал искать где проблема. При установке прав 777 не ругается и нормально загружает, но оставлять 777 не хочется.

Скажите, может  кто сталкивался с данной проблемой, и знает как её решить?

Заранее премного благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Решение:
Дать права для nginx на папку в которую необходимо загрузить файлы

```
$ sudo chown www-data /путь/к/каталогу
```

Если в папке есть вложенные папки к которым nginx тоже должен иметь доступ, то

```
$ sudo find /путь/к/каталогу -type d -exec chown www-data {} +
```

Информация взята отсюда [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444059/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-php)